# What is this switch called and what is its function?

Tags: suzuki, switches, gixxer-155

This is the photo of the switch that is present on the left handle of my Suzuki Gixxer sf 2015.

[image: the switch]

It moves forward and backward but I don't know what is it called or understand what it does. It'd be great if anyone can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the manual choke selector. When the engine is cold you pull it down in the direction of the arrow, this restricts the airflow to the engine to make the mixture rich to make it easier to start. Once the engine is heated up, which generally takes under a minute you push the choke forward against the arrow to open it up again.

Comment: Being a 2015 model it's probably an "enricher circuit" control vs. an actual choke but the end result is the same.  It provides the cold engine with a richer air-fuel mixture to help it start and run when cold.

Comment: @jwh20 - While that is a very good suggestion, the Gixxer mentioned in the question [is carburetted](https://bikez.com/motorcycles/suzuki_gixxer_sf_2015.php).

Comment: These are used on carbureted engines only.  FI has no need for this.